# How to order lists without respecting certain characters?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I currently have a string list that needs to be sorted without taking into account the following characters (`'.', ',', '-', '\''`)

**Example**

```
        var cities = new List<string>()
        {                
            "Aigle ",
            "Bulle",
            "La Chaux-de-Fonds",
            "L'Abbaye",
            "Malleray",            
            "Sierre",
            "S. City",
            "St-Aubin",
            "St-Cergue",
            "St-Gingolph",
            "St-Légier-La Chiesaz",
            "St-Maurice",
            "St-Sulpice",
            "St-Sulpice",
            "Staad"
        };
```

Making the order by default

```
var ordered = cities
  .OrderBy(x => x)
  .ToList();
```

**Output**

```
"Aigle"
"Bulle"
"La Chaux-de-Fonds"
"L'Abbaye"
"Malleray"
"S. City"
"Sierre"
"Staad"
"St-Aubin"
"St-Cergue"
"St-Gingolph"
"St-Légier-La Chiesaz"
"St-Maurice"
"St-Sulpice"
"St-Sulpice"
```

And the output I want has to be like this.

```
"Aigle "
"Bulle"
"L'Abbaye"
"La Chaux-de-Fonds"
"Malleray"
"S. City"
"Sierre"
"St-Aubin"
"St-Cergue"
"St-Gingolph"
"St-Légier-La Chiesaz"
"St-Maurice"
"St-Sulpice"
"St-Sulpice"
"Staad"
```

I got the output I want by doing this.

```
var ordered = cities
  .OrderBy(x => x.Replace(".", " ").Replace("-", " ").Replace("'", " "))
  .ToList();
```

I honestly don't know if it's okay what I'm doing.

Is there any other way to get the desired result?

Comment: If you want readability, use `Regex`. If you want performance, write a custom comparison method which operates on the strings as on arrays.

Comment: "If you want readability, use Regex" uh... okay... RegEx has a lot of advantages, but "readability" is not really one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a transformation can help you

```
var ordered = cities
                .Select(city => new { Name = city, NameForOrdering = string.Join(string.Empty, city.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray()) })

                .OrderBy(city => city.NameForOrdering)
                .Select(city => city.Name)
                .ToList();
```

This could be used as a quick and dirty way to may be get you through a hurdle or test out things but the real solution would be to use the second overload for `OrderBy` which takes your custom equality compare-r.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can order by *letters* only (we ignore, i.e. remove all non letter chars):

```
  var ordered = cities
    .OrderBy(city => string.Concat(city.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c))), 
             StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .ToList();

  // Let's have a look
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ordered));
```

We'll get the following order

```
Aigle 
Bulle
L'Abbaye
La Chaux-de-Fonds
Malleray
S. City
Sierre
Staad
St-Aubin
St-Cergue
St-Gingolph
St-Légier-La Chiesaz
St-Maurice
St-Sulpice
St-Sulpice
```

If you want to treat all non letters as *spaces* `' '` (your current code):

```
 var ordered = cities
    .OrderBy(city => string.Concat(city.Select(c => char.IsLetter(c) ? c : ' ')), 
             StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .ToList();
```

And the order will be

```
Aigle 
Bulle
L'Abbaye
La Chaux-de-Fonds
Malleray
S. City
Sierre
St-Aubin
St-Cergue
St-Gingolph
St-Légier-La Chiesaz
St-Maurice
St-Sulpice
St-Sulpice
Staad
```

The difference of the orders in `Staad` location

Answer (score 1):

One way to Sort the list while ignoring the specified characters by replacing the characters that needs to be ignored.

For example, For the list of string `cities`

```
var cities = new List<string>()
        {                
            "Aigle ",
            "Bulle",
            "La Chaux-de-Fonds",
            "L'Abbaye",
            "Malleray",            
            "Sierre",
            "S. City",
            "St-Aubin",
            "St-Cergue",
            "St-Gingolph",
            "St-Légier-La Chiesaz",
            "St-Maurice",
            "St-Sulpice",
            "St-Sulpice",
            "Staad"
        };
```

**Option 1 : Without using Regex**

```
var charList = new List<char>{'.', ',', '-', '\''};
var result = cities.OrderBy(x => charList.Aggregate(x, (c1, c2) => c1.Replace(c2, ' '))).ToArray();
```

**Option 2 : Using Regex.**

```
var charList = new List<char>{'.', ',', '-', '\''};
var regex = new Regex($"[{string.Join("",charList.OrderBy(x=>x))}]*");
var result = cities.OrderBy(x=> regex.Replace(x," "));
```

Output

```
Aigle  
Bulle 
L'Abbaye 
La Chaux-de-Fonds 
Malleray 
S. City 
Sierre 
St-Aubin 
St-Cergue 
St-Gingolph 
St-Légier-La Chiesaz 
St-Maurice 
St-Sulpice 
St-Sulpice 
Staad
```